# Create (and save) an image with a photo and some labels

Tags: uiview, uiimageview, uiimage, uilabel, photo

I'm working on a project where I want to let the user pic a photo from the library (that part works). The photo is then displayed in a UIImageView behind some UILabels (containing text, color ...) (this already works, too). Now I want to create an image with both the photo in the background and the labels in the front - is this possible and if yes, how?

Here is a simple mockup : http://www.screencast.com/users/PascalFritzen/folders/Default/media/8d3d045d-d5c0-43f9-b6c2-1ec9a53daf32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

save text in plist or DB or any array then When you want to show images with text then use this image with plist or Array to show lable(Sorry for english)

Comment: thanks for your answer even though I wasn't looking for a way to display lables etc. but rather **generate** an image. I will propably have a look at some core image stuff ... thanks anyway :)